# Does DBD::DB2 have an option to enable automatic decoding?

Tags: perl, character-encoding, db2, dbd

Does `DBD::DB2` have a switch that performs automatic decoding from UTF-8, such as `mysql_enable_utf8mb4` in `DBD::mysql`?

Comment: codepage conversion ( from database codepage into the application codepage) is normally performed by the Db2-driver (i.e in this case the ODBC driver being used to access the Db2-database that underlies DBD::DB2). This is normally invisible to the application.

Comment: @mao, Sound like you're saying the underlying C library would it convert it UTF-8 -- and that's the case for other databases as well incl the aforementioned MySQL with appropriate options -- but that's says nothing about whether DBD::DB2 produces decoded text or not. Presumably sid_com checked and it doesn't? A complete absence of `utf8` in the module's source supports that.